# How to optimize this query with EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to optimize this query using EF. This is the query that I had at the beginning.

```cs
var result = new List<string>();

_dbContext.signumid_organization.ToListAsync().Result.ForEach(organization =>
{
    if (CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations(null, organization.Id).Result > threshold)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(organization.Admin))
    {
        result.Add(organization.Admin);
    }
});

return Task.FromResult(result);
```

Now I tried optimizing it and have this right now

```cs
return Task.FromResult(_dbContext.signumid_organization
    .Where(organization => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(organization.Admin) &&
                            CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations(null, organization.Id).Result <=
                            threshold).Select(x => x.Admin).ToList());
```

But the problem is that I have an exception thrown that it cannot translate the query. Do you have any solution to my exception? Or maybe another approach to the query?

This is the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(o => !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Admin)) && ProductProvisioningRepository.CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations(
> phoneNumber: null,
> organizationId: (int?)o.Id).Result <= __p_0)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'Signumid.ProductProvisioning.ProductProvisioningRepository.CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information.
> Translation of method 'Signumid.ProductProvisioning.ProductProvisioningRepository.CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

This is what CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations does:

```cs
if (organizationId != null)
{
    return await _dbContext.signumid_credit_operation
                .Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId && x.OperationType == OperationType.Purchase)
                .SumAsync(x => x.Amount)
            - await _dbContext.signumid_credit_operation
                .Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId && x.OperationType == OperationType.Consummation)
                .SumAsync(x => x.Amount);
}
```

Comment: Databases can only be queried using SQL. EF translates LINQ queries to SQL and can't do anything that isn't possible in SQL. It's impossible to translate the local method call `CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations(null, organization.Id).Result`.

Comment: Have you tried searching the error. The chances are that `ProductProvisioningRepository.CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations` is the problem as it is not possible to do it in SQL.

Comment: @Ralf even if there was a function called that way, this isn't the way to use it.

Comment: What does `CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations` do?

Comment: If you have such complex logic you need a view. You aren't mapping objects, you're executing a complex report. For starters, `CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations` should be a `GROUP BY` query that calculates the differences between two sums. The same goes for LINQ. The badly named `signumid_credit_operation` "entity" seems to be related to the badly named "signumid_organization". ORMs deal with entities and objects, not tables. Leaking table names into clients is a very strong smell.

Comment: You should have an `Organization` property with a `CreditOperations` collection property containing `CreditOperation` objects. You wouldn't need to write a correlation, EF would do it itself. The entire operation would be eg `_context.Organizations.Where(org=>org.CreditOperations.Where(op=>op.OperationType == OperationType.Purchase).Sum(op=>op.Amount) - op.CreditOperations.....>threshold).Select(org=>org.Admin)`. That's already complex enough that a view would be easier to read. The two sum can be calculated with `SUM(IIF(OperationType=x,Amount,0))- SUM(IIF(OperationType=y,Amount,0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, everything can be done on the server:

```cs
var result = await _dbContext.signumid_credit_operation
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Admin))
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.OrganizationId, organization.Admin })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.OrganizationId,
        g.Key.Admin,
        Difference = g.Sum(x => x.OperationType == OperationType.Purchase ? x.Amount : 0) 
                    - g.Sum(x => x.OperationType == OperationType.Consummation ? x.Amount : 0)
    })
    .Where(x => x.Difference <= 100)
    .Select(x => x.Admin)
    .ToListAsync();

return result;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing work in the database and in the application querying the database.

Things before `.ToList[Async()]` happen in the database and things after happen in the application.

Here are some options:

1. Create a database function `CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations` in the database and use it in the linq query
2. Don't use a function and do the calculations inside `Where` - this will work if the calcs are simple enough to be translated to SQL. The snippet having `.Result` when calling the function suggest that it's async and that makes things complicated, but maybe it doesn't have to be async.
3. Fetch all records from the database and apply `CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations` afterwards - what you had originally
4. Write the query in SQL and use that instead of using EF.

---

Side points:

```
return Task.FromResult(_dbContext.signumid_organization
            .Where(Select(x => x.Admin).ToList());
```

should most likely be

```
await _dbContext.signumid_organization
            .Where(Select(x => x.Admin).ToListAsync();
```

The same applies to `_dbContext.signumid_organization.ToListAsync().Result.` which should be `(await _dbContext.signumid_organization.ToListAsync()).

---

*UPDATE after the CalculateDifferenceBetweenEntriesAndConsummations was posted.*

These 3 queries can be combined into one in SQL and it could look *something* like this:

```
SELECT 
 name
FROM signumid_organization org
JOIN signumid_credit_operation co on co.OrganizationId = org.Id
WHERE co.OperationType in (number_for_Purchase, number_for_Consummation)
GROUP BY org.Id
HAVING  
   (  SUM(CASE co.OperationType = number_for_Purchase THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
    - SUM(CASE co.OperationType = number_for_Consummation THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
   > threshold -- or '<=', I'm not sure
```

You could finalize this query and then executed this from your code or finsalize this query and tran translate it to LINQ.

Comment: There has to be a more optimal/unified way to do this, than just saying "what you had originally"

Comment: @MatejDodevski yes, do the complex processing with a view and map the view to entities. You can't make EF do something that's not possible with SQL